# Need help running Karate UI test on a Mobile Device

Tags: karate

I'm having some trouble getting my Karate UI tests to run on a real iOS device in SeeTest using Appium. I am not exactly sure how the tests would actually recognize and connect to the iOS device. I have included some driver caps that I think will be necessary to get it working but am not sure if I need to add more or if I added the wrong ones. Any help would really be appreciated!

```
* configure driver = { type: "<type>" }     
* def driverCaps = {"app": "<app>", "deviceQuery": "@os='ios' and @category='PHONE'", "newCommandTimeout": 2500, "baseURL": "<seetest url>", "username": "XXXXXX", "password": "*****"  }

Given driver driverCaps
```

Comment: can you share what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

take a look into karate documentation for `configure driver` https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver

It shows each key accepted in the configuration, you can choose whichever you needed for your cloud setup.

below are some of the must add `configure` keys when you are running on any remote devices

```
* configure driver = { type: 'ios', webDriverPath : "/wd/hub", webDriverUrl: "<cloudHostUrl>", port: "<cloudPort>",start: false, httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 }}
* def desiredConfig = 
"""
{
  "app": "<app>", 
  "deviceQuery": "@os='ios' and @category='PHONE'", 
  "newCommandTimeout": 20000,
  "username": "XXXXXX", 
  "password": "*****"  }
"""
* driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(desiredConfig)"} }
```