# how to run karate appium tests on cloud devices like pcloudy, headspin and etc?

Tags: karate

We are building our mobile automation tests using karate and wanted to execute the cases on cloud devices, tried changing webdriverpath value to cloud url but the value is being appended after localhost:4723/. Here i want to override localhost with remote host and port.

- configure driver = { type: 'android', webDriverPath : "/wd/hub", start: false}

Comment: try looking at other answers like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68624770/143475

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution on exploring driver configurations, remove webDriverPath and replace it with webDriverUrl like below:

- configure driver = { type: 'android', webDriverUrl: '/wd/hub', start: false, httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 }}

Comment: I was also facing the same issue. Thanks for the solution.